# Simple <ul> <li> HTML Structure : MegaMenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on project where I have created MegaMenu, which I am fetching from JSON file. Written simple logic of HTML Structure.

```css
#menu { border:solid 2px green; float:left;}
#menu ul { padding:0; margin:0; clear:both; float:none;}
#menu ul li {padding-bottom:5px; color:green; float:left; list-style:none; width: 20%;}
li a { color:green;}
#menu ul li li {float:none;}
li li a { color:blue;}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Nav Item 1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Nav Item 2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Nav Item 3</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Nav Item 4</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Nav Item 5</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
         <li><a href="#">Nav Item 6</a>
        </li>
         <li><a href="#">Nav Item 7</a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="#">SubItem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
         <li><a href="#">Nav Item 8</a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="#">SubItem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
         <li><a href="#">Nav Item 9</a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="#">SubItem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
         <li><a href="#">Nav Item 10</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Problem:** I am getting wearied output. Click on Run Code Snippet button. I found that, List items are not properly aligned.

**Desired Output:** I want to align list items properly aligned. I want Item 6 would be appear after Item 1, and there will be no white space.

Is it possible to achieve this without using JavaScript of jQuery?

Comment: In case of Megamenu, Format is decided from server side script. whole menu format can not be managed only from CSS .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add this as well

```
#menu >ul>li {
   padding-bottom:5px; 
   color:green; 
   float:left; 
   list-style:none; 
   width: 20%; 
   height:250px
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cqL6ce2e/1/)

Comment: I tried that, but Sub Items are dynamic, so it will be configured from client, can not give static height to LI.

Comment: Dharam Mali yes you can it in case you have to give `inline style` to them

Comment: Yes, that worked.. but still is it possible to reduce white space between "Nav Item 1"  to "Nav Item 6".

Same as there is lot of white space between two list items. Is there anything we can do for it.

Comment: @ Dharam Mali you need to give `width ` in `px`. Instead of `%`

Comment: Nope, this mega menu is dynamic, so client can be add or reduce item from CMS (Megento). So giving 250px fixed height will not work if client will add or remove items from categories.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Below CSS:

```
#menu {
    border: solid 2px green;
    float: left;
}
#menu ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    clear: both;
    float: none;
}
#menu ul li {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    color: green;
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    width: 20%;
}
li a {
    color: green;
}
#menu ul li li {
    float: none;
    display: block;
}
li li a {
    color: blue;
}
```